# WordPress - send email to admin on form submit

Tags: php, wordpress, email, email-attachments

I have a template with a form on it and wish an email to be sent to admin email address when the submit button is clicked.

I created `send_email.php` in template folder, so on form submit it is called:

```
<?php
   $headers = 'From: My Name <myname@example.com>' . "\r\n";
   wp_mail('test@example.org', 'subject', 'message', $headers );
?>
```

**Question:** Which files should be included in order to make the mail function work?

Comment: it is better use some Contact form plugin for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include wp-load.php, that will be in the wordpress root.

```
<?php require_once '../../../wp-load.php'; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail), `wp_mail` is a [Pluggable Function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions) and located in `wp-includes/pluggable.php`. You shouldn't have to include it (as it most likely will already be included) but in the event you just want to be safe:

```
include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/pluggable.php' );
```

You can also wrap your call with a `function_exists()` check:

```
if( function_exists('wp_mail') ) {
   // Send email
} else {
   throw new Exception('wp_mail does not exist.');
}
```